# How to create Notification with timer inside

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make notification with a countdown timer.
Am I doing wrong?

I try to update information inside notification using a countdown timer.
If the screen doesn't lock it works correctly. But in case of locked, my screen turns on each notification (so each second). So timer working correctly but it's very annoying that each second makes my screen turning on.

```
package com.example.yanec.schedulekpi;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.yanec.schedulekpi.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.yanec.schedulekpi.Fragments.DetailScheduleInfoFragment;


public class ServiceShowNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    long timeLeft;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "OnReceive");
        timeLeft = intent.getLongExtra(Constants.INTENT_PASS_DATE, 0);

        showNotification(intent, context, Parser.toStringFrom(timeLeft));

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft, Constants.COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeft -= Constants.COUNT_DOWN_INTERVAL;
                mBuilder.setContentText(Parser.toStringFrom(timeLeft));
                mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                DetailScheduleInfoFragment.isServiceWorking = false;
            }
        };

        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void showNotification(Intent intent, Context context, String time){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bar)
                .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.INTENT_PASS_NAME))
                .setContentText(time)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

If my screen is locked and I'm updating notification, my screen doesn't wake up. But if I wake up the screen by myself (don't unlock just wake up using wakeUp button), it shows me updated info. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `NotificationCompat.Builder.setOnlyAlertOnce()` when creating the notification?

Comment: Thanks, i've tried but still nothing